# Google app engine: "Stay signed in" expires too soon

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a small app written in Google App Engine, and I use the basic `login: required` in app.yaml for authentication. This gives me the Google login box, which has the "Stay signed in" option. However, even with the "Stay signed in" option I get logged out fairly quickly (within a day or two). Is there any way to extend this timeout? Is there any way around it using the `users` API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Log in to your admin console, select an app, and choose 'Application Settings'. Then, change the expiration period under 'cookie expiration' - options are 1 day, 1 week, and 2 weeks.